# How to outsource a function to a factory / service

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting confused with how to "outsource" a function that is used in multiple controllers to a factory or service..

The function checks for error messages in responses from WebAPI

```
function errorLog(error) {
    // empty old validation errors
    $scope.validationErrors.length = 0;
    // get new validation errors 
    var obj = error.data.ModelState;
    for (var key in obj) {
         $scope.validationErrors.push(obj[key]);
    }
}
```

and pushes them to the variable "validationErrors" which I use to display them:

```
<div ng-repeat="err in validationErrors">
      {{err.toString()}}
</div>
```

The function is called in the error-function of $resource-Posts and gets the raw "error" passed. I don't want to repeat the function in each controller. I'd like to have it in one place but still be able to push the errors to the "local" variable validationErrors defined in each controller.

I'd be glad for a hint in the right direction. Is this the case for a use of a service or a factory or even some other concept?

Comment: Is this structure `error.data.ModelState` going to be same for all controllers?

Comment: Yes, it is the same for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service simply acts as a common state that can be injected into controllers. If you expose say a `validationErrors` object in the service, then you simply need to bind that to any local controller scope, and any updates should propagate to all controllers using it. This should get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2863/

Service/Controller code:

```
myApp.factory('errorService', function() {
    var cont = { validationErrors: [] };

    return {
        getErrorList: function() { return cont; }
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope, errorService) {
    $scope.es = errorService.getErrorList();    

    $scope.es.validationErrors.push('Some error');
}

function MyOtherCtrl($scope, errorService) {
    $scope.es = errorService.getErrorList();   

    $scope.es.validationErrors.push('Some other error');
}
```

View (2 views using same service):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="err in es.validationErrors">{{err}}</div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="MyOtherCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="err in es.validationErrors">{{err}}</div>
</div>
```

---

EDIT:

After the comment below, I realised that you are simply trying to create a reusable function, not necessary keep a common state between controllers. In that case, pass your `$scope` into the common function inside your service.

```
myApp.factory('errorService', function() {
    return {
        errorLog: function(scope, error) {
            // empty old validation errors
            scope.validationErrors.length = 0;
            // get new validation errors 
            var obj = error.data.ModelState;
            for (var key in obj) {
                scope.validationErrors.push(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside any of your controllers, inject the `errorService`, and simply pass the POST result, along with the controllers scope, eg:

```
errorService.errorLog($scope, postError);
```

Also, you don't really need to pass the scope root into the service in your case. You could simply pass in `$scope.validationErrors`. All depends on what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. But how could the "error" object from an unsuccessfull "POST" be passed to this service? Sorry if my initial post was unclear. I've got say 5 controllers in one page. In each controller, some user-triggered post-actions can happen. I would like to inform the user of possible validation errors, separate in each controller (error in controller1 is independent of error in controller2), so I guess each controller will have to have its own "validationErrors"-array and the "error"-object would have to be posted to the factory.

Comment: Hopefully the answer is closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and time, wish I could reward you.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to implement response interceptors and capture the errors there. Since you want to have multiple independent validation errors section, you will have to some how identify the to which section does the errors belong.

And then create a directive (example list-validations) which will show the errors captured before. Either you could use a common service to share errors between your response interceptors or get your interceptors to $broadcast the errors which will be received by the directives.

The key thing is that each directive should be configurable to show only errors for a particular key and the response interceptor must identify the key for which the errors are generated.